# I need to make a Hexolnikov grid from a 2-D array AND in the row and column refer to the corresponding hexagon by painting over it

Tags: plotting, graphics, mesh

I'm new to mathematika. I need to access the hexagon by the index of the two-dimensional array that I set. This hexagon needs to be painted over, I was able to find how to set the grid only with a one-dimensional array, please help.
I need to either make a two-dimensional array out of this one-dimensional array or even find another function to create a grid with the ability to access the desired hexagon

```
hexes = Keys@
   ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][
    Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}], 1], 2];
Graphics[{Red, Polygon[hexes[[80, 1]]], EdgeForm[Blue], 
  FaceForm[None], hexes}]
Polygon[hexes[[80, 1]]]
```

that's just where the problem is that the array is one-dimensional

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

hexes = Keys@
   ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][
    Flatten[Table[{x, y}, {x, 0, 15}, {y, 0, 15}], 1], 2];

Manipulate[
 Graphics[{
   Red, Polygon[hexes[[10*(column - 1) + row, 1]]],
   EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[None], hexes},
  ImageSize -> Small],
 {{row, 1}, Range[10, 1, -1],
  ControlType -> SetterBar,
  Appearance -> "Vertical",
  ControlPlacement -> Left},
 Row[{
   Spacer[70],
   Control[{{column, 1}, Range[8],
     ControlType -> SetterBar}]}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like to be able to enter some 2D integer indices and return the Polygon on a hexagonal grid? Using [`HextileBins`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/HextileBins) to do this is interesting (and in-fact there's a similar example of making hexagonal grids under `Applications` in the Resource Function's documentation).

Your code above can be massaged into achieving this, for example something like this:

```
xBins=8;
yBins=8;
xBinsPadded=Floor[2 Sqrt[3]/3 xBins];

hexes=Join@@@(Transpose/@Partition[GatherBy[
SortBy[Keys[ResourceFunction["HextileBins"][Flatten[Table[{x,y},{x,xBinsPadded},{y,yBins}],1],2Sqrt[3]/3]],Mean@*PolygonCoordinates],
First@*Mean@*PolygonCoordinates],2]);
Graphics[{Red,hexes[[7]],Green,hexes[[7,3]],EdgeForm[Blue],FaceForm[None],hexes}]
```

[image]

However, the main problem is that the hexagonal grid does not live on the cartesian grid, but rather uses hexagonal lattice vectors.

This is perhaps a more 'rigorous' way of achieving what you want:

- First, define the hexagonal vectors

```
hexagonalLatticeVectors = {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}};
```

- Then, we write a simple function to return a Polygon at a particular Cartesian location

```
hexagonAt[{x_, y_}] := Polygon[CirclePoints[{x, y}, {Sqrt[3]/3, \[Pi]/6}, 6]]
```

- We can then loop over integer linear combinations of these lattice vectors to obtain a 2D hexagonal grid (note these are indexed using the hexagonal lattice vectors)

```
newHexes=Table[hexagonAt[{i,j}.hexagonalLatticeVectors],{i,8},{j,8}];
Graphics[{Red,newHexes[[7]],Green,newHexes[[7,2]],EdgeForm[Blue],FaceForm[None],Flatten[newHexes]}]
```

[image]